# Connect to PHP and MySQL from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I want to connect to a database from my android application, and have found a tutorial to do that ([link to tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)).

It works fine when I'm using it in the emulator, but not when I try to use it on my phone. I have tried with a WAMP server where I have port forwarded it and I have tried with a real web host (000webhost). The only difference from the emulator to the phone is the URL, where I have to provide a public IP address instead of 10.0.2.2. I have also tried with the local IP of the computer hosting the WAMP server. I know that some webhosts add ads to the code, but I'm pretty sure WAMP doesn't do that.

When I'm using the phone I get the following error from LogCat:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

*Update 1:*

I have tried using cURL to check what's returning. It returns a lot (title, bgcolor etc.), but I think this is interesting:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\android_connect\db_connect.php on line <i>28</i></th></tr>
```

It seems like it can't access the database, but I might be wrong?

When i use cURL to access localhost it returns the correct items from the database and not all the html code as the server with the public IP does.

*Update 2:*

I solved the problem with the public WAMP server. I was a noob and forgot that I had set up the server with a password.

But when I use the webhost (000webhost) from a browser I still get this error:

```
PHP Error Message

Warning: require_once(__DIR__/db_connect.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a7471305/public_html/android_connect/get_all_products.php on line 12

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/db_connect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a7471305/public_html/android_connect/get_all_products.php on line 12

Free Web Hosting
```

And I get this error from cURL:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require
</a>]: Failed opening required '__DIR__/db_connect.php' (include_path='.:/usr/li
b/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in <b>/home/a7471305/public_html/android_connect/get_
all_products.php</b> on line <b>12</b><br />
```

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: Your PHP is probably showing you an error message instead of the expected json output. Why don't try reading it?

Comment: Also it might make sense to take a look at the servers log files. It is a pretty neat thing that errors and problems are actually written in there...

Comment: check the response coming from the server. It looks like you are getting HTML page in response rather then the JSON string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Thanks to everyone who helped me.

the webhost couldn't find the file, because I was using

```
require_once( __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php');
```

To find the next php file in the same folder.
Instead I should have used:

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); 
require_once(__ROOT__.'/android_connect/db_connect.php');
```

Comment: Hello dear. I have this problem, too. I just changed `db_connect.php` file as you told (replaced with what you said) but again the same error. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the URI you are hitting is returning a HTML document rather than JSON.  Navigate to the URI in a web browser or using CURL to see what it is returning.

As several others have mentioned, PHP may be showing an error, or you could be receiving a web server error (à la 404 or 500).

Some free web hosts inject ads into HTML responses, which could cause a difference between debug and production.  You may wish to set the Response-Type header to application/json which might avoid any meddling.

Ex:

```
// This must go before any output has started, I.E. at the 
// beginning of the first loaded document
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: When I used the header in the PHP file i got the following error:        Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <html><head> of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: What did you get when you looked at the page in a web browser or via CURL?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a working environment in the emulator, try the same with your phone over WLAN. Then you have no additional steps/servers in between, which could distort your server response.

Comment: I have tried that but nothing happens for a while, and then the application crashes and gives a NullPointerException and this error message: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: Then you must first check your return values to prevent such accidents. Maybe your WLAN router blocks the route to your web server. If you check the return codes and log them to logcat, you might determine what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check this link. its for login page . But it uses php and MySql to login user if useranme and password exits in MySQL. when you will run this code and read it then you can code by yourself to do other work with php and mySQL. it is tested code . it work on android device as well.

[How to validate the user login credentials in android using PHP, MySql with the help of json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245771/how-to-validate-the-user-login-credentials-in-android-using-php-mysql-with-the/13248082#13248082)