# Unable to connect android app with mysql DB using php

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

The following is my code which connects android app with MySQL DB. When I run this in my android mobile it just displays a plain screen. There is no error in my logcat. When i run it in brower using `"192.168.1.11/city.php"` I am getting the city's  extracted from DB. But the same is not working when I run it in my android device. Please help

Android class :

```
 public class City extends ListActivity {

     JSONArray jArray;
     String result = null;
     InputStream is = null;
     StringBuilder sb=null;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     //http post
     try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.11/city.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
       //convert response to string
       try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line="0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
          Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
   //paring data
   int ct_id;
   String ct_name;
   try{
  jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
  for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         ct_id=json_data.getInt("CITY_ID");
         ct_name=json_data.getString("CITY_NAME");
     }
  }
  catch(JSONException e1){
      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
   }
    }
}
```

activity_city.xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".City" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Php Code :

```
 <?php
 ob_start();
 $host="localhost"; // Host name 
 $username=""; // Mysql username 
 $password=""; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="test"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="CITY"; // Table name 
 mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
 $sql=mysql_query("select * from CITY");
 while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

Included INTERNET permission in my Android Manifest file.

I dont know where I am going wrong. Please help.

Comment: which android OS you are using?Any errors in logcat?

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem 2.3.3 version. and no error in logcat

Comment: Hi where are you keeping the php file even i have the same code but when i type the address localhost:8080/check.php i get a 404 error..Please help i am new to android

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your phone in same network as server.

Try moving

> print(json_encode($output));

out of the loop

Comment: ya i did.. But I am not getting any Output

Answer (score 0):

your PHP code need to be change..
So i have change it and put it back..

```
<?php
     ob_start();
     $host="localhost"; // Host name              Changed
     $username="root"; // Mysql username          Changed
     $password=""; // Mysql password 
     $db_name="test"; // Database name 

     $tbl_name="CITY"; // Table name 
     mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect");          //Changed
     mysql_select_db($db_name)or die("cannot select DB");           //Changed
     $sql=mysql_query("select * from CITY");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
     {
          $output[]=$row;
          print(json_encode($output));
     }
     mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: I tried changing it.. I am grtting a text msg like "NO CITY FOUND".. But i have included more than 5 cities in my table

Comment: You need to verify table name with case.

Comment: Ya i did it.. It is CITY only and my DATABASE name is test

Comment: then first try to fetch any single row from database.

Comment: int ct_id;
String ct_name;                                                              In these two lines I get a warning ms like it is never used.. But i have used it.. why is it coming like tat

Comment: $sql=mysql_query("select ct_name from CITY");

Comment: I tried fetching a single row.. But I am getting the same msg "NO CITY FOUND"

Comment: create table CITY ( CITY_ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, CITY_NAME VARCHAR(255));
This is my SQL table query

Answer (score 0):

Where is the PHP files located.  In a local machine , or on a web server.

If the PHP files are located in local machine, you can't access it from the android application.

Also verify that you have given internet permission for the android application.

Comment: I am using LAMP server for it.. It is located under /var/www folder.. Ya I have given the INTERNET permission

Comment: is the LAMP in your local machine

Comment: Ya it is in my local machine

Comment: It cannot be accessed via the android application.  you must upload the files to some web server

Comment: I am new to this field .. to some web server means ?

Comment: I mean you need space for uploading the PHP files, so that it can be accessed every where.  This hosting must support php also.

Comment: godaddy.com provides such service

Comment: ok i will try.. but i did some programs in android which access local server.. Then how come this alone is not working ?

Comment: If so. have you checked whether there is any content in $row variable

Comment: $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)  try this instead of mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)

Comment: is there any value inside the $row variable.

Comment: you can check it like $row['column name']

Comment: It is not printing anything

Answer (score 0):

Don't use localhost when you want to test your application on your phone. Your phone can't access the PHP files on localhost.

Might I suggest hosting your PHP and SQL files online and resume testing.

Comment: Have you tested hosting it instead of using localhost?

Comment: You mean to run in browser using the PHP file link ?

Comment: Find a web host, upload your PHP files. Setup your database in it. Then test.

Comment: You have an option to test your files on localhost, if and only if your run it under an AVD, or through the emulator. The logcat should show you where it bugged down afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

1)
Are you sure ur localhost ip is "http://192.168.1.11" ?
try to put two / like this "http://192.168.1.11//city.php"

i have used this IP for my xampp "http://10.0.2.2//Mobile/login2.php"
or try this as well 127.0.1.1 or 127.0.0.1

2)
try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245771/how-to-validate-the-user-login-credentials-in-android-using-php-mysql-with-the/13248082#13248082) . if you have done something wrong in java or php code than this will help you.